# Caracteres UTF8 en SQL SHELL (windows)

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows

Tengo un script .SQL que carga una base de datos normalmente con sus valores, algunos registros de la tabla tiene caracteres especiales como tildes y Ñ, necesito que SQL shell me muestre correctamente estos valores ya que al hacer consultas WHERE y similares no me deja comparar los valores porque el usuario "Javier Alá" no aparece sino como "Javier al┘" o algo así. El propio script .sql al importarse en la base de datos establece SET client_encoding = 'UTF8'; también probé \encoding UTF8, LATIN1 etc. esto es en windows, que figura en este caso? este error no sucede en Linux.

E aquí el script (solo la seccción de tablas)

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: ciclistas; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.ciclistas (
    cod_cic character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    nomb_cic character varying(50),
    fecha date,
    cod_nac character varying(3)
);


ALTER TABLE public.ciclistas OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: contratos; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.contratos (
    cod_cic character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    cod_equ character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    fec_inicio date,
    fec_final date
);


ALTER TABLE public.contratos OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: directores; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.directores (
    cod_dir character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    nomb_dir character varying(50)
);


ALTER TABLE public.directores OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: equipos; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.equipos (
    cod_equ character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    nomb_equ character varying(50),
    cod_dir character varying(3),
    cod_nac character varying(3)
);


ALTER TABLE public.equipos OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: naciones; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.naciones (
    cod_nac character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    nomb_nac character varying(50),
    capital character varying(50),
    continente character varying(50)
);


ALTER TABLE public.naciones OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: participaciones; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.participaciones (
    nomb_pru character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    year integer NOT NULL,
    cod_equ character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    puesto integer
);


ALTER TABLE public.participaciones OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: pruebas; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.pruebas (
    nomb_pru character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    year integer NOT NULL,
    kms integer,
    etapas integer,
    ganador character varying(50)
);


ALTER TABLE public.pruebas OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: esto podria ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window